# Printing using tsc ttp-342e pro thermal printer java

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer

I am trying to print a label with printer **TSC TTP-342E Pro** industrial thermal printer. But unable to make a print. I use same program to print in laser printer **HP LaserJet M1530** and its work fine. In both case the print is initiated from a pdf. The program is communicating with the printer but it is not printing anything.
I have used pdfbox, should I go with something like bartenter?

In below program, the program will read pdf from a location and communicate with the printer to generate a printout.

**Code**

```
public static PrintService choosePrinter(String printerName) {
        PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices(); // list of printers
        PrintService printService = null;
        for(PrintService service : services) {
            String availablePrinterName = service.getName();
            System.out.println(availablePrinterName);
            if(service.getName().contains(printerName)) {
                printService = service;
                break;
            }
        }
        return printService;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            LOGGER.info("===== PRINT JOB 2 STARTED =======");
            Properties prop = getProperty();
            String printerName = prop.getProperty("printername");
            //String fileLocation = prop.getProperty("filelocation");
            String printStatus = prop.getProperty("enableprint");
            Double height = Double.valueOf(prop.getProperty("height"));
            Double width = Double.valueOf(prop.getProperty("width"));
            Boolean enablePrintPageSetup = Boolean.valueOf(prop.getProperty("enablePrintPageSetup"));
            PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(location));
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            Paper paper = new Paper();
            paper.setSize((width*72), (height*72)); // 1/72 inch
            paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());
            PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
                if(enablePrintPageSetup) {
                    pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
                }
            pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
            Book book = new Book();
            PDFPrintable pdfPrintable = new PDFPrintable(pdf, Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT);
            book.append(pdfPrintable, pageFormat, pdf.getNumberOfPages());
            job.setPageable(book);
            PrintService printService = choosePrinter(printerName);
            if(printService != null) {
                if(Boolean.parseBoolean(printStatus)) {
                    LOGGER.info("Print enabled  ");
                     job.setPrintService(printService);
                     job.print();
                } else {
                    LOGGER.info("Print disbaled  ");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No PDF printer available.");
                LOGGER.info("===== No PDF printer available. =======");
            }
            System.out.println("===== PRINT JOB 2 STOPPED =======");
            LOGGER.info("===== PRINT JOB 2 STOPPED =======");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            LOGGER.error("Error : ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static Properties getProperty() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {

            File jarPath=new File(App_1.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
            String propertiesPath=jarPath.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(" propertiesPath-"+propertiesPath);
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesPath+"/config.properties"));
            location = propertiesPath + "/printpdf.pdf";
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace(); 
           LOGGER.error("Error : ", e);
        }
        return prop;
    }
```

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? There have been problems reported with label printers, but it's usually trouble with orientation or stuff cut off, but never "nothing". Do these problems happen with all files?

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I have added a video below
https://expirebox.com/download/7df41fd5eefcabf542d8622e25e57995.html

Comment: Not exactly nothing, The page is moving back and forth but nothing is printing

Comment: The version of pdfbox is 2.0.9

Comment: Please update to 2.0.11, that is the current version. Then try 2 things: 1) replace `new PDFPrintable(pdf, Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT)` with `new PDFPrintable(pdf, Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT, false, 300)`, this converts to a 300dpi image before printing. Also try printing from PDFDebugger (just download it from the pdfbox download page).

Comment: What jdk are you using? I do my development on 1.8.181.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will try these

Comment: Its worked fine. The issue was with paper size. Thanks for the info

Comment: Physical paper size, i.e. wrong paper in the printer? Or wrong size in the code? Consider answering it yourself, this may help others.